# Enable expand/collapse functionality in CME forms for embeddable field sections

Tags: cme, content-manager

I wanted to understand feasibility of implementing expand/collapse functionality in content creation forms in CME for embeddable field sections (sections using embedded schema). By default everything is open in CME in terms of fields on the CME forms and there is no OOB way to enable expand/collapse for the embeddable sections. 
I wanted to check if someone has already implemented this since it seems a common usability requirement. I also wanted to understand what are the options for the same.

**Edit 1:**
Adding functionalities I want to implement:

1. Default behavior as expanded or collapsed for embedded sections
2. individually collapse or expand sections
3. "Expand All" and "Collapse All" for embedded sections

Comment: If this is for all embedded fields, a GUI extension that changes all embedded Schema fields would be the best approach. To control when the fields hide, check out the approach used by the [Field Behavior Extension](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/fbi). You might only apply your extension or styles to only fields that are enabled for this.

Comment: Also consider the default behavior and context -- should fields always show collapsed by default, does the embedded Schema store the fact it's collapsible or does the field that use the embedded Schema determine collapsed state, and would you want a "show/collapse all" option.

Comment: @AlvinReyes yes I am looking to add this for all embedded schema fields. I've added functionalities I want to implement to the question

Comment: A GUI extension would be the best fit for this--anyone who's done this could add an answer. Harder, but also possible, is your own editor (the CME and XPM are editors themselves), which I wouldn't suggest as a first recommendation. Also consider starting a [Tridion Ideas] account to make a more formal suggestion to product development.

Comment: @AlvinReyes I hope somebody has done it which I can refer (that's the good part about active community of users). I do have Tridion Ideas account and have submitted a couple of ideas as well. I will definitely submit an idea for this same as well. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Nice and thanks for submitting those ideas. You _could_ offer a StackExchange bounty to encourage an answer, but I'm _almost_ sure this hasn't been built yet.